# Import table in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, import

I am using Oracle Sql Developer. I have a table in one schema. I want to copy this table into another schema with its all data. How can I do this?
Thanks,

Comment: The best way is to give the second schema the appropriate permissions on that table.  That way you only have one set of data to maintain.

Comment: I'm sorry if the following sounds stupid but just to be sure. Please clarify what do you really mean by `schema` because in Oracle it has different meaning - the user (and all user's objects). Do you want to copy that table on the same database server instance from one database user to another? Or rather you want to unload table and it's data on one server and then import it to another database instance?

Comment: I want to copy one table on the same database server from one database to another. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM schema2.old_table);
```

You need to make sure  you grant proper access to the schemas.  Here is a [Tutorial](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php)